# Copying a generator without blowing up memory

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I'm writing a python class that finds all possible [magic squares](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html) given an integer `size` and a generator for the possible `combinations`. These combinations are tuples of length `size**2` and are split into a `size`×`size` grid. The code itself works fine, but reusing the generator appears to require `itertools.tee`. In the example shown below, this causes the memory used by the thread to jump to 300MB since every value in the iterator is being stored in a list.

```
from itertools import permutations, tee

class MagicSquare:
    def __init__(self, size, combinations):
        self.size = size
        self.range = range(self.size)
        self.combinations = combinations

    def getGrid(self, entries):
        return [ entries[self.size*i:self.size*(i+1)] for i in self.range ]

    def checkGrid(self, grid):
        check_sum = sum(grid[0])
        if any( sum(row) != check_sum for row in grid ): 
            return False
        if any( sum(row[col] for row in grid) != check_sum for col in self.range ): 
            return False
        if sum(grid[diag][diag] for diag in self.range) != check_sum: 
            return False
        if sum(grid[diag][self.size-diag-1] for diag in self.range) != check_sum: 
            return False
        return True

    def solutions(self):
        combinations, self.combinations = tee(self.combinations)
        for entries in combinations:
            grid = self.getGrid(entries)
            if self.checkGrid(grid):
                yield grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    combs = permutations(range(20,30), 9)
    ms = MagicSquare(3, combs)
    for solution in ms.solutions():
        for row in solution:
            print row
        print
```

There are two obvious solutions to this issue that come to mind. First, I could ask for a function that provides a generator rather than ask for a generator itself, but this requires the user to wrap their generator expression. Second, I could cache the solutions. For the sake of argument, let's say I no longer want to check the diagonals if there aren't a sufficient number of solutions, so I'll need to update `checkGrid` and reiterate over `combinations`.

So, my question is: Is there really no way to copy a generator without creating this potentially huge memory issue? I don't care about retaining a partial state of the generator, I just want it to iterate over the same values as the original generator.

## Edit

It looks like in Python 3.X, you can use `copy.deepcopy` to copy `itertools` objects whose dependencies are all pickable.

Comment: To clarify, this is a hypothetical question for a project that's going to be dealing with a lot of `itertools` iterators. Implementations of the two solutions suggested above are trivial, I'm wondering if it's *absolutely impossible* to copy an `itertools.xxx` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is impossible...

The following happens to work well with `itertools.permutations`. Don't assume that it will work with any iterable, because it won't!

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> combs = permutations(range(20,30), 9)
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> combs2 = deepcopy(combs)
>>> next(combs)
(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)
>>> next(combs2)
(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)
```

Comment: This appears to only work in Python 3.X as both `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy` are throwing errors in Python 2.7. I'm going to go test with other `itertools` objects.

Comment: You didn't mention a specific version of Python so I assumed CPython 3.x.

Comment: It might be worth changing for this benefit, there's nothing really holding me to Python 2.7, I just didn't expect the behavior to be different.

Comment: Looks like they added pickling support to the `itertools` iterators in Python 3, so as long as their dependencies are picklable, `itertools` iterators will be picklable and deepcopyable. Won't help when generators are involved, though.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like the answer to my question might be "generators are probably not copyable, but since `itertools` supports picking in Python 3.X, those objects can be copied using the built-in `copy` module." Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to copy an arbitrary iterator. A very small number of specific iterator types support copying; the only one I know of is `itertools.tee`. In general, though, iterators can have way too many uncopiable dependencies for a copy mechanism to be part of the iterator protocol.

You're only running into this problem because you've written an API that tries to take a one-shot iterator and return a reusable object. If you're going to take an iterator, you should design your API to return an iterator instead of a `MagicSquare` object you can create once and then call `solutions` on repeatedly.

For your use case, I would recommend making `MagicSquare` a generator. The primary, probably only use for this class seems to be calling `solutions` for an iterator of solutions. Why not simply replace the class with a function that does what `MagicSquare(size, combinations).solutions()` currently does?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a generator, pass a function which returns a new generator whenever it is called. This will allow `MagicSquare` to iterate over the combinations as many times as needed without keeping them in memory.

To paraphrase your code:

```
class MagicSquare:
    def __init__(self, size, get_combinations):
        ...
        self.get_combinations = get_combinations

    ...

    def solutions(self):
        for entries in self.get_combinations():
            ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    combs2 = lambda: permutations(range(20,30), 9) # 
    ms2 = MagicSquare(3, combs2)
    ...
```

Comment: In my question, I noted that "I could ask for a function that provides a generator rather than ask for a generator itself, but this requires the user to wrap their generator expression." It seems like it just isn't possible to copy an iterator.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I missed that part.

Answer (score -1):

Since your generator is self-contained and deterministic, the best way to work with two copies is to create two of them. (If necessary, modify the signature of `MagicSquare` to accept two generators; but it looks like you want the copy for other purposes?)

```
combs2a = permutations(range(20,30), 9)
combs2b = permutations(range(20,30), 9)
```

Comment: But what if I want to reuse the generator an arbitrary or unknown number of times?

Comment: You create another one each time? In the general case you describe, you can't know what you'll need again so there's no getting around full caching of the output, like `tee` does. Whether you make another or clone as in the accepted answer makes little difference--  you need to get involved if you plug in a new generator. `deepcopy` is clever, but relies on your being careful and testing (properly) every new input.